# Unexpected '?' in LaTex reference

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Recently, I met a problem in LaTex paper writing. I want to link a website in my reference while '**?**' appeared in my context even if I have compiled the .tex file for many times.

Here is my ref.bib file,

```
@misc{Jira,
 title = {Jira bug tracking system},
 howpublished = {\url{http://issues.apache.org/jira/}},
}

@misc{Bugzilla,
 title = {Bugzilla bug tracking system},
 howpublished = {\url{https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/}},
}
```

and then I refer this website in my .tex file,

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}                 % document begins
...
\cite{Jira}                      % cite the reference
\cite{Bugzilla}
...
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
\bibliography{ref}    
\end{document}
```

but the generated pdf looked liked this `[Jir(???)]` and `[Bug(???)]`, It's strange that other references are all showed correctly while these website references are showed '**?**'. That's the problem I really cannot figure out, who can help me and thanks a lot :)

Comment: I use the latex compiler TeXstudio and also compile both pdflatex and biblatex in order. BUT other book or papaer references are all showed correctly while above website references are all showed ? :(

Comment: The problem is author-year citation. BibTex wants to create a short-hand for each bibliography entry consisting of three letters of the author and two letters for the year. Since you don't give a year for the online resources, BibTex fails in creating a shorthand, displaying that the year is missing.

Comment: @Tiuri, thanks for you solution and '**?**' is gone. Then I have another question, that is `
Which year should I select to cite the website`, for instance I want to cite google(https://www.google.com/), which year should I select, 2009 or 2017 ?

Comment: You never want to cite Google, but rather the website you found using Google. Furthermore, you probably don't want to cite a website in general, but rather a specific subsite (for a example a blog post with some release details instead of just the blog itself). Try to find on the website a date when it has been created (if there is none, you should probably not cite it). Give the date you looked yourself on the website in the field `note`.

Comment: @Tiuri , thanks a lot! I want to select your answer as the solution. I suppose that maybe I should use `\footnote{}` to replace `\cite{}` if I really want to cite a website :)

Comment: @Tiuri, please answer my question then I will select you as the final answer to close my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `spbasic` citation style uses abbreviations made out of three letters of the authors name and two digits from the publication year to refer to the individual references. If the year is missing in one bibliography entry, it will print instead some question marks to show: something is missing here. The easiest way (i.e. without changing the bibliography style) to cure this is to just add a year to the relevant bibliography items.

Some more suggestions on (scientifically) citing websites:

- Citations are meant for referencing information, not for telling the reader where to find online tools. So usually you might want to give the URL of some web portal inline or as a footnote, rather than put it as a citation.
- In general, you should only cite websites (or rather: webpages) that have a clear indication of an author and a publication year. So instead of putting the main URL of a webtool as a citation, you might want to cite some webpage that announces or introduces the tool or some new version of it. Look for example for blogposts related to the tool.
- When citing a website, you should usually give the date you accessed the website, since information on the web can change. Don't use the `year` field for that but rather fill the `note` field, e.g. with "Accessed on August 8th, 2017".

Comment: Very good answer to solve my problem!